# How is this calculus derivative substitution legal?

Tags: calculus

A car is traveling along the road with a speed of $v = 2s$, where $s$ is in meters.  Determine the magnitude of it's acceleration when $s = 10$ m

Why is the following legal?

It tries to find $a_t$ (the tangent velocity of the car on the circular road) with the following equation: $a_t = \frac{dv}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{dv}{ds}v=2 \cdot 2s = 4s$.

Why is it legal to substitute $v=2s$ into $\frac{ds}{dt}$? Shouldn't $\frac{ds}{dt}=v(t)$? Why can we substitute $v(s)$ into this to get $4s$?

Comment: all of $s, v, a$ are functions of time but there are also extra relations like. $\frac{ds}{dt}$ is $v(t)$ but you are given that $v(t) = 2s(t)$ and you just chain rule.

Comment: It is legal as long as you are not doing the calculation while driving.  http://www.textinganddrivingsafety.com/texting-and-driving-stats/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See it this way: $v=2s(t)$. $s$ is a function of $t$. Hence $v$ is a function of $t$ too.